# How to remove Hashtag in URL using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to remove the hashtag in my URL. For instance

`http://localhost/Tech/technology/#method`

In the above URL I need to remove `#` tag and the result will be like this:

`http://localhost/Tech/technology/method`

Can you help me please?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to amend the current URL in the address bar, or you want to amend the links in your `a` elements?

Comment: Want to change current URL without # tag

Comment: Can i ask for PHP ?

Answer (score 1):

Use **encodeURIComponent** it will percent encode your URL string.
ex:

```
var set4 = "ABC abc 123"; // Alphanumeric Characters + Space
```

`console.log(encodeURIComponent(set4)); // ABC%20abc%20123 (the space gets encoded as %20)`

It will solve not only # but for all special characters.

Answer (score 0):

First get the url, replace # with '' and reload:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    url.replace('#', '');
    location.href = url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using javascript.

```
document.location.href = String( document.location.href ).replace( /#/, "" );
```

```js
var url = "http://localhost/Tech/technology/#method"
url = String( url ).replace( /#/, "" );
console.log(url);
alert(url);
```

Comment: Thank you. Second thing is, i have more than 5 menu items, each item contains sub menus, when i click to sub menu(not current page sub menu) link goes to particular div, i assign ID to all div's. After clicked, it goes correctly, the thing is in the URL # tag with div ID is displayed i need to remove that # tag. For eg:  http://localhost/Tech/technology/#method (#method is div ID), how to remove # tag in this scenario